# Error 405 in ajax post with javascript to laravel method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to create a post ajax request through a btn click and I'm getting error 405. I've search a little and I've included token part in my file in header,

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And in my ajax request,

```
$.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            type: "POST",
            url:"/bebedouros/saveInfo/",
            data:{
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",        
                IdVisitaBebedouro:id,
                TipoBebedouro:tipoBebedouro,
                Higiene:higiene,
                Fluxo:fluxo,
                Comprimento:comprimento
            },
            processData:true,
            success: function(data){
                alert('informação gravada com sucesso');
            }
        });
```

And in my routes file I have this,

```
Route::post('/bebedouros/saveInfo/','BebedourosController@saveInfo');
```

And the method saveInfo exists in BebedourosController

I've also tried to insert token in ajax setup and nothing. Anyone knows another solution? It looks like the onclick is calling the method and return 301 and then 405 bu with debugger it only enters once in the ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that your function is missing or you are not giving the correct path inside ajax function. First name the route

```
Route::post('/bebedouros/saveInfo/','BebedourosController@saveInfo')->name('saveInfo');
```

Then call the route function inside your ajax function

```
$.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            type: "POST",
            url:"{{ route('saveInfo') }}",
            data:{
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",        
                IdVisitaBebedouro:id,
                TipoBebedouro:tipoBebedouro,
                Higiene:higiene,
                Fluxo:fluxo,
                Comprimento:comprimento
            },
            processData:true,
            success: function(data){
                alert('informação gravada com sucesso');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Maybe because i'm not using form this happen? Normally I use a form to submit data but for this section I need to submit using a ajax request and not a form.. can you answer this doubt?

Comment: I think the `url` attribute of ajax is not picking the right path may be just `/bebedouros/saveInfo/`. Here we have given the proper route to it which you can check in the `page source`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Header:**

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Place the following code above your Ajax call and remove the token inside the data in Ajax.

**Ajax:**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've already tried that, but thanks.  Setting a name to my route and passing that name into "url" have solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

The possible issue is with the `type` value that is being assigned it will be `application/json` but currently it is being assigned `POST`. POST is valid for method only.  And also modify the ajax call header with the token info as mentioned by @arunj